# Equivalent formulas for Laplace-Beltrami operator

Tags: differential-geometry, laplacian, index-notation

I am trying to derive the [following equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Gradient,_divergence,_Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator):

$$
g^{jk}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^j \partial x^k} +
\frac{\partial g^{jk}}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}+
\frac{1}{2}g^{jk}g^{il}\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}
=
g^{jk}\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^j \partial x^k}- g^{jk}\Gamma^l_{jk}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^l}
$$

I was thinking of using [this equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Christoffel_symbols,_covariant_derivative) for the Christoffel symbols:

$$
\Gamma^m_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}g^{mk}(\frac{\partial g_{ki}}{\partial x^j}+\frac{\partial g_{kj}}{\partial x^i}-\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k})
$$

**EDIT after the suggestion in the comments**

Now, when substituting this equation in the right hand side of the first equation, I get for the relevant term:

$$
g^{jk}\Gamma^l_{jk}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^l}=
g^{jk}(
\frac{1}{2}g^{il}
(\frac{\partial g_{jl}}{\partial x^k}
+\frac{\partial g_{ik}}{\partial x^j}
-\frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial x^i})
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^l}
)
$$
exhanging $i$ with $j$ and $l$ with $k$ and reordering terms:

$$
=
g^{jk}(
\frac{1}{2}g^{il}
(\frac{\partial g_{ik}}{\partial x^l}
+\frac{\partial g_{jl}}{\partial x^i}
-\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^j})
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}
)
$$

$$
=
g^{jk}(
\frac{1}{2}g^{il}
(\frac{\partial g_{ik}}{\partial x^l}
+\frac{\partial g_{jl}}{\partial x^i})
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}
)
-
\frac{1}{2}
g^{jk}
g^{il}
\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^j}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}
$$

$$
=
\frac{1}{2}g^{jk}g^{il}
\frac{\partial g_{ik}}{\partial x^l}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}
+
\frac{1}{2}g^{jk}g^{il}
\frac{\partial g_{jl}}{\partial x^i}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}
-
\frac{1}{2}
g^{jk}
g^{il}
\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^j}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}
$$
Now, using the suggestion that

$$g^{ij}g_{jk} = \delta^i_k$$
gives
$$\frac{\partial (g^{ij}g_{jk})}{\partial l}=0$$
and so
$$g^{ij}\frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial l}=-g^{jk}\frac{\partial g^{ij}}{\partial l}$$

the previous formula becomes

$$
-
\frac{1}{2}g^{jk}g_{ik}
\frac{\partial g^{il}}{\partial x^l}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}
-
\frac{1}{2}g^{jk}g_{jl}
\frac{\partial g^{il}}{\partial x^i}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}
-
\frac{1}{2}
g^{jk}
g^{il}
\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^j}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}
$$

$$
-
\frac{1}{2}
\frac{\partial g^{il}}{\partial x^l}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}
-
\frac{1}{2}
\frac{\partial g^{il}}{\partial x^i}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}
-
\frac{1}{2}
g^{jk}
g^{il}
\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^j}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}
$$

$-\frac{\partial g^{jk}}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}-
\frac{1}{2}g^{jk}g^{il}\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}$

where I use the fact that $g_{ik}=g_{ki}$ and $g^{ik}=g^{ki}$ and that I can rename indexes on a term that fully "contracts" or if they are not used elsewhere.

Do my assumptions make sense?

thanks

Comment: Use the fact that $$ g^{ij}g_{jk} = \delta^i_k$$ and the partial derivatives of this equation.

Comment: @Deane thanks a lot for your suggestion, I have tried again and I think I got it now. Would you be so kind as to review my attempt, if you have a chance?

Comment: I won’t check this carefully but there seems to be a typo in the first line of the second equation after EDIT. There’s a $k$ that I think should be a $j$.

Comment: @Deane i have also exchanged the $g^{jk}$ and $g^{il}$ terms at the beginning of the expression if that is what you mean, obtaining the same terms as before. calculations aside, I just wanted to understand if my assumptions for the calculation where right, i.e. if I took your suggestion right and the other assumptions I stated at the end of my question. thanks